# A number theory problem

Tags: contest-math

Let $S$ be a set of real numbers satisfying the following conditions:

i. $0$ is in $S$.

ii. Whenever $x$ is in $S$ then $2^x+3^x$ is in S.

iii. Whenever $x^2+x^3$ is in $S$ then $x$ is in $S$.

How can I prove that $S$ contains at least two distinct numbers between $0$ and $1$, i.e., (0, 1)?

Comment: By between do you mean elements in $(0,1)$ or in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @OliverE.Anderson (0, 1)

Comment: Sumac problem ..its actually cheating :P

Comment: @wellwisher: please flag the questions you claim are cheating and list a source and I think the moderators will remove it!

Comment: @wellwisher: [This SUMaC](http://math.stanford.edu/sumac/)?

Comment: @Did  Yes that sumac only.

Comment: [SUMaC](http://math.stanford.edu/sumac/) is no longer accepting applications for 2013.

Comment: I don't think the number theory tag is appropriate, removing it.

Answer (score 3):

by (i) $0 \in S$

by (ii) $2^0 + 3^0 = 2 \in S$

now $2 = 1^3 + 1^2$ so by (iii) $1 \in S$

now $1 = \theta^2 + \theta^3$ where $\theta = 0.7548776662\ldots$ so by (iii) $\theta \in S$.

Comment: You need one more as $1$ doesn't count. But it's not hard to find

Comment: @RossMillikan, I needed to show 1 is in S before I could show theta=0.754877... in S

Answer (score 2):

Use ii to show $2$ is in $S$. Then solve $x^3+x^2-2=0$ to.get two more elements, one of which is $-1$ so ii.gets you $5/6$. Solve$x^3+x^2=1$ for another.

Added: if you replace condition i by: there is a positive number in $S$, then you can use iii alone because $x^3+x^2$ is monotonic. Given $y$ in $S$ there is $y'\lt \sqrt[3]y$ in $S$ and you can keep going down until you are below$~1$

Comment: You don't have to solve the equation, just show there is a root in $(0,1)$ and it is not $5/6$

Comment: $-1$ is not a root of $x^3+x^2-2$. But it is a root of $x^3+x^2$, and so it is in $S$ because of (i) and (iii) immediately.